# Maven: exec-maven-plugin auto reload?

Tags: java, maven

Is it possible to have `exec-maven-plugin` auto-reload upon source code changes?

So when running:

`mvn exec:java`

Then save a java change, and have it auto-reload the change?

Comment: By auto-reload you mean compiling classes ?

Comment: @11thdimension Yeah, compile and either hot reload or restart the app I suppose

Comment: I don't know about any such plugin, but you can try creating a simple program which watches your code directory and restarts mave exec. Check here for watch service https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Comment: @mtyson I need the same feature and I didn't find anything